# undefined local variable or method `params' when implementing Search Field

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, search

I am doing a tutorial from Stuck.io on implementing a search field on my admin model, so someone can search for a specific admin. the form is appearing, however when I try to use the search I am getting an error field and I don't know where I've gone wrong.

The Exact error I am getting is:

```
NameError at /admins
undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Class:0x007f91e39df950>
```

**My custom Devise Admin Controller:** (to create an index and show page)

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!

  def index
    @admins = Admin.all
    # Search Query
    @admins = Admin.search(params[:search])
  end

  def show
    @admin = Admin.find_by_admin_ident(params[:id])
  end

end
```

**Routes for my custom Admin controller:**

```
           admins GET    /admins(.:format)                  admin#index
            admin GET    /admins/:id(.:format)              admin#show
```

**My Admin Model:** Search method

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Search Functionality
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      @admins = Admin.where(["name LIKE ?","%#{params[:search]}%"])
    else
      all
    end
  end

end
```

**And finally my Search form:**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="info-block">
    <%= form_tag admins_path, :method => 'get' do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'form-control', :id => 'admin-search-field' %>
      <center><%= submit_tag "Search Users", :class => 'btn btn-default btn-sm', :id => 'search-btn' %></center>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your input! Please let me know if you need anything more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the `params` hash inside the model. This is only accessible from controllers.

Instead of:

```
@admins = Admin.where(["name LIKE ?","%#{params[:search]}%"])
```

Use:

```
@admins = Admin.where(["name LIKE ?","%#{search}%"])
```

And then in the controller, pass the value as you are doing already:

```
Admin.search(params[:search])
```

Comment: Awesome that did the trick! just a side question here, is there any way to search multiple columns ie by a fires and last name? and to search where cap letters are not manditory? right now in my demo i have three test users but when i lower case their names it wont display? ill give you best ! thanks

Comment: Yes, of course. If you just want some simple functionality, then you could implement it all manually - e.g. in Postgresql, just use `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE` for case insensitivity. If you're looking for some more advanced tools, I'd recommend something like Ransack (https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) - check out this screencast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack) for a quick start guide.